Deploying Keyvault with private endpoint gives error - Updating the name of existing nic not allowed
I am trying to create an ARM template for an existing Keyvault. This Keyvault is also associated with a Private end point. When I am trying to deploy to same keyvault again ideally it should not give any error but in my case I am getting error as below :
 "code": "NameOfExistingPrivateEndpointNicCannotBeChanged",
 "message": "Private Endpoint /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/test-kv-ep contains existing NIC name test-kv-ep-nic which does not match request's custom network interface name . Updating the name of existing nic not allowed."

Although I am not trying to update NIC name anywhere in my template.
Below is the ARM template that I am using:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the key vault."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the Azure location where the key vault should be created."
      }
    },
    "enabledForDeployment": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies whether Azure Virtual Machines are permitted to retrieve certificates stored as secrets from the key vault."
      }
    },
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies whether Azure Disk Encryption is permitted to retrieve secrets from the vault and unwrap keys."
      }
    },
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies whether Azure Resource Manager is permitted to retrieve secrets from the key vault."
      }
    },
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().tenantId]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the Azure Active Directory tenant ID that should be used for authenticating requests to the key vault. Get it by using Get-AzSubscription cmdlet."
      }
    },
    "pvtEndpointConnKv": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "pvtEndpointConnVMSS": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetId1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetId2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "privateLinkServiceConnectionName1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "privateLinkServiceConnectionName2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "deployPrivateEndpoint": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Set to true to deploy the private endpoint."
      }
    },
    "accessPolicies": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "List of Key Vault's access policies"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2024-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "Standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "defaultAction": "Deny",
          "ipRules": [],
          "virtualNetworkRules": []
        },
        "accessPolicies": "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
        "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForDeployment')]",
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": "[parameters('enabledForDiskEncryption')]",
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
        "enableSoftDelete": true,
        "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
        "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
        "enablePurgeProtection": true,
        "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
      "name": "[parameters('pvtEndpointConnKv')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subnet": {
          "id": "[parameters('subnetId1')]"
        },
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('privateLinkServiceConnectionName1')]",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
              "groupIds": ["vault"],
              "requestMessage": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am trying to deploy a keyvault with a private end point. I am getting the error as you are trying to update NIC name but I am not trying to change it through ARM template. How can I deploy this keyvault with a private end point.

can you check the name of NIC in portal linked with keyvault was refered with correct name check for any syntax errors or space that you try to refer because any change in the name from actual info leads to modify the existing one @abhijeet

In portal the NIC name is 'test-kv-ep-nic'. I am not trying to modify it from the template. I dont't know why it is trying to modify it.

YOu cant refer or use the existing NIC to keyvault need to create a new one @abhijeet

You are not explicitly modifying the NIC in the template, but since the Private Endpoint (test-kv-ep) is tied to the NIC, any modification to the Private Endpoint triggers this error. @abhijeet

Is it good to specify the NIC name explicitly?

Check with the approach mentioned below which creates keyvault with private end point @abhijeet


Deploying Keyvault with private endpoint gives error - Updating the name of existing nic not allowed

As per the error description My takeaway point is you created a keyvault and private endpoint. Somehow you try to redeploy the keyvault and private end point configuration.
Before doing this if you redeploy the private endpoint is being treated as a new deployment as youre using the same arm configuration, and Azure does not allow modifications to certain properties, such as the NIC name, once the resource is created.
ARM deployment:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Key Vault."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for resources."
      }
    },
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().tenantId]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Azure AD tenant ID for the Key Vault."
      }
    },
    "accessPolicies": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Access policies for the Key Vault."
      }
    },
    "subnetId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource ID of the subnet for the private endpoint."
      }
    },
    "privateEndpointName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Private Endpoint."
      }
    },
    "privateLinkServiceConnectionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the private link service connection."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2023-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "defaultAction": "Deny",
          "ipRules": [],
          "virtualNetworkRules": []
        },
        "accessPolicies": "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('privateEndpointName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subnet": {
          "id": "[parameters('subnetId')]"
        },
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('privateLinkServiceConnectionName')]",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
              "groupIds": [
                "vault"
              ],
              "requestMessage": "Please approve this connection for the Key Vault."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones",
      "apiVersion": "2024-06-01",
      "name": "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net",
      "location": "global",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks",
      "apiVersion": "2024-06-01",
      "name": "[concat('privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net/', parameters('privateEndpointName'), '-vnet-link')]",
      "location": "global",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones', 'privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', parameters('privateEndpointName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "virtualNetwork": {
          "id": "[substring(parameters('subnetId'), 0, indexOf(parameters('subnetId'), '/subnets'))]"
        },
        "registrationEnabled": false
      }
    }
  ]
}



Deployement:
az deployment group create --name DeployKeyVaultWithPrivateEndpoint --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file main.json --parameters keyVaultName=testsasamk privateEndpointName=testsample privateLinkServiceConnectionName=tesatsample subnetId=/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/vksb-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testsamplevnet/subnets/default tenantId=tenantId



Refer:
Integrate Key Vault with Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn
